# Accessing a multi-dimensional object from inside a v-for

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects

I'm probably doing something dense, but having bashed my head against it for a while now I thought I'd ask here to see if anyone else can see where I'm going wrong.

So, this is simplified somewhat but essentially I'm using vue.js and have a v-for loop to make a nice list, but I'm wanting to access data from another multi-dimensional object using the loop value as the key:

```
<li v-for="bar in foo.bars">{{ list[bar].name }}</li>
```

where list is defined in `data` as follows:

```
list: {
  "somekey":{"name":"Joe Bloggs","email":"joe.bloggs@"},
  "someotherkey":{"name":"John Doe","email":"john.doe@"},
  "anotherkey":{"name":"A N Other","email":"a.n.other@"}
  etc.
},
```

`bars` itself is also multidimensional, but the specifics of that don't really matter here. What is important is that the resultant `bar` value is a key for `list`.

This results in the following console warnings/errors:

> vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

However if I use:

```
<li v-for="bar in foo.bars">{{ list[bar] }}</li>
```

I get no errors, and the following output:

- {"name":"Joe Bloggs","email":"joe.bloggs@"}
- {"name":"John Doe","email":"john.doe@"}
- etc.

Which is as I would expect. Similarly if I use:

```
<li v-for="bar in foo.bars">{{ list['anotherkey'].name }}</li>
```

I get

- {"name":"A N Other","email":"a.n.other@"}

Again this is as I would expect. So all the object data is there and accessible (and appears to be ok through the console, and the Vue DevTools add-on), just not when using `list[bar].name` (or `list[bar][name]`, `list[bar].email`, etc.) in the v-for, which is a bit of a head scratcher.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: My first thought is that `list` is being created or updated asynchronously. Is that true?

Comment: It's populated via an axios.get from a php file returning json, it's pretty much the first thing run on the page. However, the issue is the same if I just hard-code `list`.

Comment: Well if the `foo.bars` array is populated when the template renders but the `list` array is still waiting on the `axios.get` response, you would definitely get that error. The error, at the base level, indicates that there is a value in the `foo.bars` array that does not exist as a key in the `list` array at the time of rendering the `v-for`. Without seeing your full code it's hard to help any further than that.

Comment: Yes, quite, but as I said it's the same error even if I hard code list  :)

Comment: uses `{{ list[bar] && list[bar].name }}`, but it may causes multiple empty `<li`> elements. or try `<li v-for="bar in foo.bars" v-if="list[bar]">{{ list[bar].name }}</li>`

Comment: @Sphinx That works!!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OP states in the comment, data property=list is created or updated **async** by axios.

In order to avoid the error `vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"`, one solution is uses `v-if` to make sure `{{ list[bar].name }}` will be rendered only when `bar in list`.

So you should change your template to below:

```
<li v-for="bar in foo.bars" v-if="list[bar]">{{ list[bar].name }}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to @Sphinx's suggestion, here is the answer in all it's code glory: http://jsfiddle.net/megalomaniac/8j7otq0h/

```
<div id='app' v-cloak>
  <div v-for='foo in things'>
    <h3>{{ foo.title }}</h3>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="bar in foo.bars" v-if="list[bar]">{{ list[bar].name }}</li>
        <!-- <li v-for="bar in foo.bars">Doesn't work: {{ list[bar].name }}</li> -->
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div v-html="foo.description"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list: {
      "somekey":{"name":"Joe Bloggs","email":"joe.bloggs@"},
      "someotherkey":{"name":"John Doe","email":"john.doe@"},
      "anotherkey":{"name":"A N Other","email":"a.n.other@"}
    },
    things: [{"title":"Title01","bars":["somekey"],"description":"Desc01"},
      {"title":"Title02","bars":["someotherkey","anotherkey"],"description":"Desc02"},
      {"title":"Title03","bars":["somekey","brokenkey"],"description":"Desc03"},
      {"title":"Title03","bars":["somekey","anotherkey"],"description":"Desc03"}]
  }
})
</script>
```

Basically I needed to account for instances when the some of the data might be bad or missing (look for "brokenkey" in the JSFiddle). While this does apply to async issues in my case is wasn't because of async but because the some data was actually missing - which was the one thing I thought I could be certain wasn't at fault (that'll teach me to think testing the returned JSON's validity, the existence of the objects in the console, trusting the source, etc. were enough of a check).